# How do I hide markup in Markdown mode with use-package?

Tags: init-file, use-package, markdown, markdown-mode

I'd like to hide the markup in my Markdown buffers. I can do that manually using markdown-toggle-markup-hiding. However I'd like to configure this once and for all in my init.el so that I don't have to do this manually every time.

I tried setting markdown-hide-markup to 1, but it doesn't work. I believe I'm missing something here in my use-package configuration.

If anyone knows a fix, can you let me know?

Here are the things I've tried that do not work.

```
;; Markdown Mode
(use-package markdown-mode
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq markdown-asymmetric-header t
        markdown-hide-markup 1)
  :config
   (add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook
             '(lambda ()
                (setq markdown-hide-markup t)
                (visual-line-mode)
                ))
  (progn
    (with-eval-after-load 'markdown
      (markdown-toggle-markup-hiding))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `markdown-hide-markup` needs to be set before markdown mode starts, so the markdown-mode-hook probably doesn't do anything. But it's buffer-local, so I think you need to use `setq-default` instead of `setq`.
2. You set `markdown-hide-markup` to t, and then you toggle it, which might be turning it off. Not sure.

This works for me:

```
(use-package markdown-mode :ensure t
  :init
  (setq-default markdown-hide-markup t))
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much :)